# PHP variable add another page

Tags: php

I have two websites. I would like to simply echo message on the second page (example: echo "FOO") at the commented place on the first page. How can I solve it?

Second page: msg.html

```
echo "foo";
```

First page: index.php

```
   <form id="form_1" method="post" action="dbconn.php">
<table id="table_form">
<tr>
 <td colspan="2" id="table_main">Jelentkezés</td>
</tr>
<tr>
 <td>Név</td>
 <td><input class="text_box" type="text" name="nev" placeholder="Név"></td>
</tr>
<tr>
 <td>E-mail cím</td>
 <td id="bubble_pos"><input class="text_box" type="text" name="email" placeholder="Email cím">
 <div id="bubble_box">
 <div class="bubble"><?php echo ///////////;?></div>
 </div>
 </td>

</tr>
```

Comment: Put it in the session

Comment: `I have two websites.` -- like on different domains? Or are you talking about two different pages? You could do `echo file_get_contents('http://path/to/file/msg.html');` if on another domain, or just include the file as a partial using PHP's `include()` statement if in the same project.

Comment: How to with session?

Comment: Two different pages. First page: foo/index.php;  Second page: foo/msg.html